# Need a command that combines val() and text()

Tags: jquery

I am currently trying to manipulate the contents of two different types of controls (label and input) with jquery. As of now I am doing this by using two commands.

```
if(true)
{
   myControl.text('@types.Text');
   myControl.val('@types.Text');
}
```

Is there one command that can do both?

Side note: I have tried both html() and append() but I think these are variations on text() and val()

Comment: What about `myControl.text('@types.Text') || myControl.val('@types.Text')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use something like this in my JavaScript utilities

```
$.fn.setValue = function(val) {
    return this.each(function() {
        switch (this.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
            case "input":
                switch ($(this).attr("type").toLowerCase()) {
                    case "hidden":
                    case "password":
                    case "text":
                        $(this).val(val); break;
                    case "radio":
                    case "checkbox":
                        this.checked = val; break;
                } break;
            case "span":
            case "button":
            case "label":
                $(this).html(val); break;
            case "select":
            case "textarea":
                $(this).val(val); break; 
        }
    });
};
```

Then you can use your new function with almost any type of element without having to worry about what it is.

```
var myControl = $('#someSelector');
myControl.setValue('@Types.text');
```

Comment: Great answer. Only tiny change I made was moving button to input section. I am not sure if this is better in long run but it worked in my case.

Comment: @dan_vitch: good catch, I'm missing a "button" type in the "input" section. The "button" case towards the bottom is for `<button />` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own, something like:

```
$.fn.tval = function (value) {
    if (this.is(':input:not(:checkbox):not(:radio)')) {
        this.val(value);
    }
    else {
        this.text(value);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no command combining `text()` with `val()`. Is there any problem in writing custom function for this? By the way: although `text()` and `html()` are almost the same, `val()` and `append()` are VERY different - check the jquery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

if you also want to support the get side of the val() and the text():

```
$.fn.tval = function(value) {
    if (value) {
        if (this.is(':input:not(:checkbox):not(:radio)')) {
            this.val(value);
        } else {
            this.text(value);
        }
        return this;
    }else{
        if (this.is(':input:not(:checkbox):not(:radio)')) {
          return this.val();
        } else {
            return this.text();
        }
    }
}
```